# Jenkins for windows need java installed on system?

Tags: windows, .net, jenkins

I am in the process of configuring jenkins on server. There is no Java installed on server.
From the link, I understood that Jenkins windows installer will install JRE so that no need of external java installation.[jenkins windows installer](https://jenkins.io/blog/2011/03/23/windows-installers-are-now-available/)
But when I ran the command java-version it returns error that no java installed. So it required to install java seperately? Is it needed for jenkins to run java on the server?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the setup installs a private JRE (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510169/what-are-the-differences-between-private-jre-and-public-jre) so it is not visible outside of Jenkins dir.

Comment: So Jenkins can make use of this when needed? No need of Java installed?

Comment: Yes, Jenkins is a Java app and cannot even start without JRE. With private JRE, you _have_ Java installed, just privately using xcopy deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You need Java installed because Jenkins generally works from a tomcat server and installing tomcat requires java. If you are in windows, then you need to set the correct PATH variables as well - `JAVA_HOME` variable to be specific and also add the bin folder to the PATH

Comment: I have installed Jenkins and there is no Java installed in the VM. But it is working fine. So where this will cause problems because of Java not installed?